# How to change windows desktop theme programmatically

Tags: delphi

I want to change windows desktop theme by delphi code.

I found in google for help o did not get. I got some code help to change theme for an application . But i want to change theme of desktop.

So plz. help me .....Is there any api functions...

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818/how-do-i-change-the-current-windows-theme-programatically

Comment: Isn't this the thing that you aren't supposed to do because the user owns that setting?

Comment: It would be really annoying if something like this could work. I would consider such a programm for "maleware"...

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no API for changing the theme for the whole desktop. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

try InqSoft Windows Scanner to find window that you need ( desktop ). After that you will need to read WINAPI manual to use window messages and functions properly ( + functions about DC. you can google something like this: " draw on desktop delphi ")

And as I remember, you can change shell parameter and set your own programm with built in desktop routine etc ( by default shell = explorer.exe )