# How to close the personalization window after specified time via command prompt

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have some vbs code that will automatically change my windows theme via cmd as well as close it after the operation completes. The personalization window opens, Windows changes the theme, and then the personalization window closes. The problem is, sometimes the window doesn't close after changing the theme and I'm wondering why. Also, is there a one-liner code in cmd (or vbs that can execute through cmd) that just closes the personalization window? Thanks in advance for your help! My code used is as follows:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""

Wscript.Sleep 1600
WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Run` call is being done asynchonously so your script will continue without waiting for `Run` to complete. This is fine, and it's what you need in your situation. But if it takes longer than 1600ms to launch the Desktop Properties dialog then `AppActivate` and your `SendKeys` commands are being sent to a nonexistent window. Have you tried increasing the sleep time to see if it works?

You can also test the availability of the window in a loop. `AppActivate` returns `True` if the window is found and `False` otherwise. For example, here's a snippet that tries for 10 seconds to see if the window appears (checking each second)...

```
For i = 1 To 10

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    If WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties") Then
        WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
        WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
        Exit For
    End If

Next

' If i > 10, it failed to find the window.
```

Comment: I have tried increasing the time and sometimes it still does not work. I was wondering if I can manually close it regardless of if it is open or not? In cmd I can write: taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Personalization" and this will close the window. But I don't know how to run this command from vbs. Would you know how? Thank you for the help by the way, I will try your method and let you know if it works.

Comment: OK, I was just confused because in your original example you were looking for a window named "Desktop Properties" and I noticed on Windows 7 that's it's entitled "Personalization". Did you try using "Personalization" instead of "Desktop Properties" in your VBScript? Also, what's the final `{F4}` for?

Comment: Right, I got this code actually from another source and I'm not entirely sure what the {F4} is for. I will try the Personalization, but it does work about 70% of the time. I'm just trying to figure out a way to make sure that at least once the program starts it'll close (the code I posted runs when the program opens, but not starts yet). So I  was thinking of just writing another file that just closes the window. Woudl you know how to write that in vbscript to send the command to cmd? Thanks again.

Comment: My guess is that `AppActivate` is failing every time (because you're using the wrong window title). The 70% of the time when it works is when the Personalization window becomes the _active_ window. This is usually the case but not always. As long as the window becomes active, `SendKeys` is going to work (regardless of `AppActivate`).

Comment: I just changed the name and it still functions the same way. I did however increase the sleep time and it is working. I'm thinking maybe earlier I had only changed the time by a second or so and that was not enough but this time I increased it by 2 and it's working every time! Thanks for the help Bond!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a similar solution, I came up with the following powershell:

```
Function Get-WindowHandle($title,$class="") {
   $code = @'
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@
   Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace MyWinAPI -Name GetWindowHandle
   return [MyWinAPI.GetWindowHandle]::FindWindow($class, $title)
}

Function Close-WindowHandle($windowHandle) {
   $code = @'
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
      public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int flags, int idk, int idk2);
'@
   Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace MyWinAPI -Name CloseWindowHandle
   #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx
   $WM_CLOSE = 0x0010
   return [MyWinAPI.CloseWindowHandle]::PostMessage($windowHandle, $WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
}

Close-WindowHandle $(Get-WindowHandle 'Personalization' 'CabinetWClass')
```

Comment: When I open the Personalization window then run this, PS simply returns `True` (and the window does not close. I also tried just entering the command `Get-WindowHandle 'Personalization' 'CabinetWClass'` and PS returned `0`. What does this mean?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used this, but I get the same result. Note that "Personalization" is passed in as the window title. My guess is that this worked for me on Windows 7 and that the window titles have since changed since I upgraded to Win 10.

Comment: The following returns a window handle when the Settings > Taskbar window is open: `Get-WindowHandle "Settings" "ApplicationFrameWindow"`. And passing that handle to `Close-WindowHandle` seems to still work. I'm finding the class by using Autohotkey's "Window Spy" program.