# How to change the current Windows theme programatically in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, windows-8, windows-8.1

From Windows XP to Windows 7, you could change the current the with the command line: ([How do I change the current Windows theme programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818/)). But in Windows 8.1 (and windows 8 I suppose), it doesn't work.

The only way I can do it is with WinaeroThemeSwitcher (http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.209).

How can I do it from native commands or from C#? WinaeroThemeSwitcher proves that it is possible.

Comment: use JustDecompile, ILSpy or other tools to look how he done it with his tool

Comment: no idea. I voted you up, because it is a legitimate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how. Using ILSpy (with few corrections) helped a lot. Thank you  magicandre1981.

I also found an implementation online afterwards using COM objects GUID (class ThemeManagerHelpClass):

https://github.com/opkorz/CS199_Thesis/blob/master/Implementation1/CL_Utility2.ps1

Comment: Please help me. I used JustDecompile and ILSpy to decompile it, and made some corrections, but it just doesnt work! 
Can you tell me which one should be edited after the decompilation?

Thanks  in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the code in the github link? I used it with a theme file:
themeManager.ApplyTheme(themeFilePath);