# how to change theme using command prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-themes

I am working on a desktop app that provide users multiple themes. My requirement is when user click on a theme that should be applied on the desktop. I am using a command line found from here [How do I change the current Windows theme programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818/how-do-i-change-the-current-windows-theme-programatically). But its not working it opens a window that is
 [image]

and nothing happens.

Also how to add a thumbnail image like in windows personalize Window...

[image]

I mean how to show a theme in this way so that all image can be visible on one another

Comment: or any other way to run a slideshow of desktop background in user system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the current Windows theme programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818/how-do-i-change-the-current-windows-theme-programatically)

Comment: Anoop, if you read the linked question, it explains how to automatically close the Theme dialog which pops up.

Comment: Yes  i read it but even after closing it my theme doesn't changes. so i mean what are the probable issues are happening in this case.